The Brisk curriculum or the more Classic Lithuanian Yeshiva curriculum?
For a Bocher after Beis Medrash in the USA, what Yeshivas (maybe 3) in Yerushalayim follow the "Brisk" method/curriculum and focus on the tractates that deal with Kodshim, etc. and what Yeshivas (maybe 3) in Yerushalayim would follow the more Classical Lithuanian Yeshiva method and focused on Shabbos, Sukka, Psachim, etc.

There are far too many to compile a comprehensive list, but included in the main ones are:
Kodshim

Brisk (R' Avraham Yehoshua)
Pragers
R' Dovid Solveitchik
R' Yechiel Solveitchik
R' Shalom Shechter
Yagdil (I think)

Nashim/Nezikin

Mir
Bienstocks
Fivelsons
Belskys
Mishkies

